# iframe is not working in some browsers

Tags: javascript, iframe

I'm currently working on a website that generates iframe code that can be copy-pasted on a site. I'm currently using a Mac to debug it.

The issue is in some browsers the iframe does not show. Specially when I'm using a Mac. I did try it on Windows and it does work. The autogenerated code is this:

```
<iframe id="cmgplayer" src="http://siteName.com/player/?accountID=7&&acctName=dmgenesis&&playerID=2&&app=&&stream="  frameborder="0" scrolling="no" align="middle" style="width:100%;" ></iframe>
<script>
    resizeFrame();   
    window.addEventListener("resize", resizeFrame);   
    function resizeFrame(){     
        var iframeProperty = document.getElementById("cmgplayer");
        var frameWidth = iframeProperty.clientWidth;     
        var newHeight = frameWidth *.56;     
        iframeProperty.style.height = newHeight+"px";   
    }// resizeFrame
</script>
```

It somehow does work on Windows.

Comment: Please elaborate on "it doesn't work".

Comment: "Using a Mac" sounds like a misdiagnosis. Most likely you are either only testing on one very specific browser or you are changing some other factor (like the origin of the page hosting the iframe (e.g. by adding www to the front of the URL)).

Comment: Which 'in some browsers' are you pointing at specifically?

Comment: Can you try to write something inside the iframe tag and tell us if the "not working" browser show you that text? If it does not sounds to me there is a problem in the loading of the inner page of the iframe. Can you try to put google.com as src instead that your page just to make a test?

Comment: Thanks for all you answer. I appreciate it. The issue was of HTTPS: instead of using HTTPS: I just wrote http: and because of it the browser is blocking the website inside the iframe. on a windows PC it's not a concern but when I use my MAC it's an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure this one out,

the site is on http**S** and the url is on http. that's why it's not displaying the the url.

Sorry I think I have a confusing question to start with